# View Controller shows black screen instead of fetching users from Firebase database Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I go to the HomeViewController the screen is to totally black. I actually want to fetch the users to put them into TableViewCells. I am using Firebase as a database and Swift as a language. Help me to accomplish this.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var users = [User]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchUser()
    }

    func fetchUser() {       
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = User(dictionary: dictionary)
                self.users.append(user)

                //this will crash because of background thread, so lets use dispatch_async to fix
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }

    func handleCancel() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "resultCell", for: indexPath)
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = user.email
        return cell
    }
}

class UserCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**Presenting Home View Controller through SWRevealViewController under LoginButton**

```
let vc : SWRevealViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Architecture**
[image]

Comment: could you please show code how you present your `Home View Controller`? PS: btw you have 2 questions here: 1. why does it show black screen 2. how to fetch data

Comment: @TungFam i have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding this to the `ViewDidLoad` everything went right.........

```
    menuHome.target = SWRevealViewController()
    menuHome.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

You may be not setting the RootViewController of You navigation controller.

[image]

**Solution**

Select the segue between `SWRevealViewController` and the `NavigationController`. In the attributes inspector, set the segue identifier to **“sw_front”**. This is the default identifier that indicates a transition of front view controller.

For the segue between `SWRevealViewController` and the sidebar view controller, set the segue identifier to **“sw_rear”**. This identifier tells `SWRevealViewController` that the controller represents the rear view

Comment: it is set as you suggested but i dont know why it is showing black

Comment: have you added `SWRevealViewController ` as Identifire ?